# 100% disk usage Windows server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, hp-proliant, hard-drive

We have HP Proliant G6 server with 4 1.5Tb SATA disks. 2 RAID 1 arrays and 2 logical drives 1.5Tb.

One day ago I mentioned twith resmon that disk usage is 100% and i\o speed is not more then 4Mb\s

Server almost hangs..

How can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: Bits or bytes? You're using `b` where you should probably be using `B` and it can change the meaning. What is your RAID controller? Are you using hardware or software RAID? Is it battery-backed? Do you have write caching enabled? Are you running the latest firmware? What is the rotational speed of your SATA disks (which probably shouldn't be in a server)? How are you measuring this performance?

Comment: Hello!
I'm using hardware raid on HP ProLiant DL120 g6, RAID controller doesn't show any problems.

Speed of SATA drives is 7200rpm

Read speed is 2-3-4 Mb\s

Write-cache i Windows system is switched off

I'm measuring peformance with Resource Monitor on Windows 2012 r2

Comment: Don't use Resource Monitor for that. Use a purpose built benchmarking tool like SQLIO. Also, I think you are saying Mb when you mean MB. Please pay attention to that. They are different.